# Какие есть инструменты редактирования Rich text?

Tags: c#, unity3d, строки, текст, richtextbox

Имеется Rich text с форматированием:

1. < color>
2. < b>
3. < i>
4. и др.

Пример текста:

<color=#000000 padding=25,25,0,0>text< /color>

Из текста нужно произвольно удалять символы таким образом, чтобы не сломать форматирование.
На даный момент перебираю текст, удаляю руками. Скорее всего занимаюсь велосипедостроительством, должен быть инструмент, который автоматизирует процесс.

С помощью чего в Unity(C#) можно работать с Rich text?

Comment: как один из вариантов String.Format("<color={0} padding=25,25,0,0>{1}< /color>", "#000000", text)

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, не понял как мне это поможет. У меня на входе есть произвольная строка типа такой:
<color=#000000 padding=25,25,0,0>text<b>NEW</b>< /color><i> hello</i>
Мне не известно где и что (в смысле где текст, а где теги форматирования) в ней расположено.

Из этой строки нужно как-то удалять символы (которые не отвечают за форматирование). Допустим нужно удалить N символов с конца. Если теги окажутся пустыми - то теги нужно удалить.

Comment: Возможно, стоит взять парсер XML или HTML.